# How to run AngularJS 2 with Codeigniter 3 in Windows OS..?

Tags: php, html, angularjs, node.js, codeigniter

I downloaded **AngularJS 2** `'Hello World'` program from the [site](http://www.developer.com/services/writing-my-first-angularjs-2-app.html) and followed the procedures to run the program. I have successfully executed program in **AngularJS 2 without Codeigniter 3**.

But in Codeigniter 3 environment i don't know how to run `'Hello World'` program.

#### I have the following questions:

1. Path to run the commands like `npm install` and `npm start` in codeigniter 3.
2. Where to place the folders and files like `app`,`pakage.json`, etc..?
3. Is it correct to run the project in codeigniter..? Example: `http://localhost:port/angular-2-codeigniter-3-project/controller`

Help me to work this in codeigniter 3. And also notify me if i missed some procedures to run the program.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://blog.pisyek.com/create-todo-app-with-codeigniter-3-angularjs-part-2/

It is actually a good start to get the intergration working.

In reply to the solution(the answer needed to be expanded): optional is to create a restFul base in codeigniter to deliver the wanted data.
Build the components and elements using (example: angular-cli) and prefill the components with lorem ipsum values. After you have created a full angular application compile it to production and include the scripts to your views. I usually tend to use the template controller by Glenn Stovall because it is robust and dynamic to not overload the pages with unused js files.

I hope this helps you find your solution.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The user asked for Angular2 and your answer is for angularjs 1.x? Irrelevant.